# Deepin OS: Wireless Not Detect

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I am beginner using Deepin OS linux. once installed i can not find the wifi connection. if on Windows OS, I might check in device manager to make sure that the wireless driver is installed correctly. what about Deepin OS linux? what can I do?

[image: Screenshoot]

**Output: [lspci -knn | grep Net -A3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2id9.png)**

```
brother@brother-PC:~/Desktop$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: wl
```

Comment: You'll need to load the modules/build the modules in to the kernel to support your wifi card.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will identify your hardware. Then, and only then, someone may be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]` is the Realtek RTL8723DE chipset, not yet natively supported by your kernel version therefore it needs a driver.

In a Terminal do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 4.11-up
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```

Source: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de

Comment: Output after execution `dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414`:
  

**Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=4.9.0-deepin13-amd64...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.9.0-deepin13-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.**

Comment: I followed the explanation of [this link] (https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git) and solved my problem. I appreciate your help and your time. thanks you very much

Comment: @flyingbird013, it's great that this answer solved your problem.  The system automatically reposts questions after awhile that don't have an accepted solution, so this thread showed up again a year later.  It would be helpful if you accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That will indicate that the problem is solved and identify that there is a proven solution here for other readers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.3_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.3_amd64.deb
```