# I just installed Deepin OS but it cannot find a WIFI network card

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers

I just installed Deepin OS, but it cannot find a WIFI network card.  This is the screenshot of my settings.

[image]

This is the detail of my network card:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Kernel modules: wl
```

I found [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1310036/deepin-os-wireless-not-detect), but the answer there didn't help, so I assume my issue is different.

Answer (score 1):

This could help even if you're running on deepin because you're still using apt, try using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work#635629

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for you contribution, but whilst this may potentially answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential information here, and provide the link for reference- even though it's another SE site (AskUbuntu). Please **edit your answer** to include that information. Thanks :)

Comment: Deepin is debian based. There is no `add-apt-repository`.